# How to ask effective questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I'm trying to work on posting at least one DnD related question each day and I'm finding it  difficult to actually get questions that get decent responses from the community. My best question ([Can the Dungeon Master have a player character](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137643/can-the-dungeon-master-have-a-player-character) was posted around 5 years ago and recently my questions have only been receiving barely above 10 up-votes. I really enjoy seeing how helpful the community is and really want to keep posting questions but I can't seem to ask questions that don't get closed.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions that could help me ask effective questions?

Comment: I don't know what tag fits this the best so sorry if support is the wrong one for it. (it was the tag that seemed to fit it the best

Comment: FWIW, you should not be trying to meet some minimum quota of questions per day. That will have you run into trouble. Just focus on asking actual questions representing real problems you're having, as and when they come up.

Comment: "*my questions have only been receiving barely above 10 up-votes.*" and is that bad?!

Comment: Some of this is just going to be the vagaries of what questions resonate with which readers.  There's not much you can do about this, but there's also not much you *should* do about this.  Despite the gamification mechanisms built into the stack system, you should be asking questions that you need answers to, not that get you a lot of points.

Comment: To underscore that idea, questions about systems other than the big hitters (various D&D and Pathfinder, mainly) will get fewer points because of smaller pools of expertise and interest.  That doesn't mean they're less valuable to *you* if you're an aficionado of those game systems.

Comment: @Novak actually, small and fringe systems often get quick upvotes just for *existing* and then are forgotten while our scrutiny for D&D questions is higher.

Comment: A core principle of StackExchange is a gamified reputation system — but StackExchange is not a game, ask questions about actual problems you face.

Comment: I know it's not a game as I said in the question I enjoy seeing how helpful the community is. A lot of the time while my questions might just be random and for my curiosity I genuinely want answers as they might end up being useful in the future. (also I don't know what is a good amount of upvotes but from what I've seen usually good thought provoking questions get around 30 which in my eyes means my questions aren't actually good)

Comment: @Argo A good question is one that solves your problem and future querents problems, votes do not provide sufficient feedback in that regard. But interesting/compelling/common/controversial questions, those that garner a lot of votes, should also be good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The title grabs attention

A good question has a title that grabs attention. Either the title is descriptive, or it is for some other reason making people think "huh?" and look at it.

### Framing

A good question is more than just the question. It has a good frame. It explains the problem well and contains all details.

### Ask actual questions, not hypotheticals

Sometimes a question appears dragged in by the hair, because it's not an actual problem the person faces or something they try to understand, but made up just to ask a question. Avoid making up questions for asking a question's sake.

### Avoid opinion-based questions

You tried to ask a question [what is correct roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204478/how-does-one-correctly-role-play) within the last half hour. I was typing up an answer there, as I saw that it was answerable from my point of view with a frame challenge. However, others did mention that people might feel it was opinion based. I didn't manage to answer in time till the question was deleted. I am not saying it was a bad question, but indeed, most certainly it *could* have resulted in opinion-based answers.

### Bear with time

I have a few very well received questions, going up tp +40. However, only 33 of those are 10 or more upvotes, 42 are 5 or less votes, 5 of them without answers. That doesn't make my 40% of questions that only get 5 votes *bad* questions. They just are not grabbing attention or people are not interested in the question. In fact, 5 of my questions have less than 50 views, 10 less than 100, 43 don't make 200 views, and only 19 make it to 1000 or more views. But as time goes on, you still get votes and answers, even on very old questions. Like, my top-voted question, untouched since 2021, just got a vote in the last week.

Comment: I think the “correct roleplaying” question was just fine. There is a distinct problem and there are expert-based solutions to that problem that are not opinion-based at all.

Comment: @doppelgreener it *was* fine imho. though my answer would have been that there is no *correct* way, there's only fun ways and not fun ways.

Comment: I partially agree with your 3rd paragraph. While I agree that one should refrain to ask question for the sake of asking a question, sometimes one needs some clarification about rules, without having faced an actual in-game problem.

Comment: @Eddymage "I don't understand the rule" is an actual problem.

Comment: True, but often a request for an actual in-game problem  that involves that ruleis asked to be put in, in order to have "a good question".

Comment: from what I saw the roleplay question was bad and opinion based but I un-deleted it.

Comment: @Trish As long as the Fun/Not Fun axis includes everyone at the table :)